# chef server on AWS, ERROR: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef

I'm trying to get a chef server running on a CentOS instance on AWS. I've been following Opscode's directions here: http://www.opscode.com/blog/2013/03/11/chef-11-server-up-and-running/

However, when I enter 
`knife configure -i` 
and the options (including correct server fqdn, which I can ssh into from my laptop and ping from itself) the responce it always the same: 
`ERROR: Connection refused connecting to myserver.amazonaws.com:443 for ...`

Any suggestions of what could be misconfigured? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Chef so cant say anything about any config files but plz make sure that in the security group port is open and there is no change which is needed in any chef config files to allow connection.
ping and ssh doesn't ensure that port 443 or other relevant ports are open, ssh is port 22 and ping is ICMP packets only

Answer (score 0):

I always use `knife configure` and add chef API's end-point (that's running on port 4000) when it's asked...

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the hostname to something resolvable (command `sudo hostname 'something.com'`) solve it?